# area of rectangle whose vertices are roots of equation $z\overline{z}^3+ \overline{z}z^3=350 $

Tags: complex-numbers

We have a complex number $z=x+iy$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\overline{z}$ represents conjugate $$z\overline{z^3}+  \overline{z}z^3=350 $$
so i proceeded by taking $z\overline{z}$ common thus 
$$z\overline{z}(z^2+\overline{z}^2)=350$$
$$2(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)=350$$
$$(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)=175$$
now what to do ?
note:area is **integer value**

Comment: Your last equation is equivalent to $$x^4 + y^4 = 175,$$ which has infinitely many solutions. Your derivation seems also fine, so the problem may be ill posed.

Comment: Maybe but it was asked in some entrace exam , there would be some way around to solve this?

Comment: Of course, it should be $x^4 - y^4 = 175$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have

$$(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)=175=5^2\cdot 7$$

Since $\;7=3\pmod 4\;$ , it isn't a sum of squares, and so aren't $\;5\cdot 7=35\;,\;\;175\;$ , so the only possibility *in integers* (and positive, if we're to denote by them geometric quantities) is

$$\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=25\\{}\\x^2-y^2=7\end{cases}\implies x^2=16\implies x= 4\;,\;\;y=3$$

**Added:** Thus the rectangle's vertices are $\;(\pm4,\pm 3)\;$, with an area of $\;48\;$

**All the above under the assumption we want integer lengths** , which is *not* given.

Comment: Options for the given question were
a)48 b)32 c)40 d)80
and 48 was given to be correct one

Comment: The question is very ill-posed if it doesn't mention *integer* lengths since, as was noted in the comments, there are infinite options.

Comment: And, anyway, the options given are incorrect....are you reading the question or trying to remember it?

Comment: i am reading it from question paper

Comment: And you're sure the given numbers and information are correct?

Comment: Note that if $(4,3)$ is a vertex, the other three vertex might be $(-4,3)$, $(-4,-3)$, $(4,-3)$ and the area would be $\mathbf{48}$.  **but** also $(4,3),(3,4),(-3,-4),(-4,-3)$ is such a rectangle (area $14$) and $(4,3),(-3,4),(-4,-3),(3,-4)$ a square of area $50$.

Comment: and there it is the answer

Comment: Jeje...and just now I realized and added that info!

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón, the options $\;(\pm3,\pm)\;$ are off as they don't fulfill the two quadratic equations in $\;x,y\;$ .

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by $7=3(mod 4) $ ?

Comment: Right... I just took @gewr 's comment in the question $x^4+y^4=175$ without checking it was wrong.  The right one being: $x^4-y^4=175$

Comment: @Tesla, $\;7=3\pmod 4\iff 7=3+4k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ In the present case $\;k=1\;$, of course. It is a very well known theorem in basic number theory that a positive integer is the sum of two squares iff all its prime divisors which are $\;3\pmod 4\;$ appear with an even power in the number's prime decomposition.